# Can I launch URLs from command line in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, url

Can I launch URLs directly from the command line in Windows?

Comment: I always thought iexplore www.google.com would work i'm sure i've done it in the past  loads of times, but it didn't. So, stick c:\program files\internet explorer,  in the path and it will.  Personally I make another environment variable for long boring stuff like MOREPATH="c:\program files\internet explorer". Then path=.......;%MOREPATH%   That's in control panel..system..environment variables. now iexplore www.google.com will damn well work!

Comment: You can create a local .URL file (just drag and drop the address from your browser to your desktop). Then run that URL file from your command line (with "call" or "start")

Answer (score 89):

Yes, with the start command. Example:

```
start http://www.google.com
```

That will use the user's default browser.
[As stated by Joey](https://superuser.com/questions/36728/can-i-launch-urls-from-command-line-in-windows/36730#comment36859_36730), you should use a different format for URLs with special chars:

```
start "" "http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: Remember to use `start "" "some://url?with=special&chars=:->"` otherwise things will break.

Comment: Nice, another nice feature for this solution is that you can also do `start www.google.com` but I admit it will not always work.

Comment: I need to remove the quotes, otherwise it opens a new CMD.

Comment: @daVe you need an empty quote pair like Joey said if the url is quoted

Comment: @Joey When the comment is more useful than the answer...

Comment: @Joey I submitted an edit to this answer to save the next guy a few clicks.  Pretty lame that surrounding a parameter in quotes changes the program's behavior.

Comment: When  the FIRST parameter has quotes, it is taken as the title of the CMD window. That's why `start "" thingie` run thingie, but `start "thingie"` runs CMD.

Answer (score 10):

you can use

```
start http://www.google.com
```

Interestingly only following  combination are working for above url :

```
start www.google.com
start http://google.com
start http://blog.google.com
```

But following is not working :

```
start google.com
start asp.net
start blog.google.com
```

I think it is because in the later example google.com and asp.net are treated as files and it tries to find google.com file and gives error on not finding it.

I think it is hardcoded for www. Any better guesses ?

Comment: It's probably because `start` works for several applications (not only websites). providing at least `www` or `http://` the `start` command links your URI to the HTTP protocol, while it could probably run other protocols.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `explorer <url>` which will use your default browser.

Comment: @ekaj Your right :/ First time i tried it it didn't work - for some reason it now worked ... comment deleted

Comment: Windows Server 2016: First time it displays a prompt asking you to choose a default browser, with a checkbox asking "Always use this app".

Answer (score 5):

What's "launch" in this context?  You can `start http://www.foo.bar/` or the like, your default browser will come up and visit that URL -- is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this in Powershell:

```
Start-Process "URL"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cheap approach that will work on XP at least:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\IExplore" "http://www.msn.com"
```

Comment: Ouch... and msn.com no less.

Comment: first thing that came to mind...for no apparent reason whatsoever

Comment: Cheap in what sense?

Comment: @Kazark: cheap in that it opens up the URL in Internet Explorer as opposed to whatever the default browser happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

you can run this below command and it will redirect to google chrome browser

```
C:\>start 'http://www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using start works fine, but it leaves the browser open to the web page.

How can you connect to a URL either 1) use the browser method and automatically close the tab, or 2) do it without starting the browser?

Mark.

Answer (score -6):

From C# code you could just run this (cmd-start equivalent):

```
Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

You've launched your url from a command-line directly (i.e. without running another program first).

Comment: Is this `C#`? This does not work for me on Windows 7 using `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Tried this in PowerShell and it didn't work. Must be C#. Does this really answer the question?

Comment: This is not CMD syntax, nor does it seem to be valid Powershell. I could remove my downvote if the poster updated his answer with details.