# Open URL with VIM in Ubuntu WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[You can use the `gx` command to open a URL in vim.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458294/open-url-under-cursor-in-vim-with-browser) Is this possible when using vim within Ubuntu in WSL?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes, no action was visible. Does it work for you on the same setup?

Comment: It seems to temporarily go back to the console before returning to vim.

Comment: There is a uservoice page for this feature. See this [link](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/6511299-make-links-clickable). Microsoft is currently working on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In vim, run:

```
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="cmd.exe /C start"
```

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1252579/72210), [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/36730/72210), and [this quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39510377/461834).

You can also put this in your .vimrc file. Since I share my vimrc file between computers, I used the following to make .vimrc_local file for this OS-specific setting:

```
" From: https://devel.tech/snippets/n/vIIMz8vZ/load-vim-source-files-only-if-they-exist/
function! SourceIfExists(file)
  if filereadable(expand(a:file))
    exe 'source' a:file
  endif
endfunction

call SourceIfExists("~/.vimrc_local")
```

Comment: Oooh, guys, thx so much!! You cannot imagine how long I'm looking for a solution for this problem. I'll open a beer tonight, yaaaay!